# Monotouch - UIView.Animate does nothing in a subview why?

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios

I have a virtual function called DoRotate() that does an animation of a subview rotating.  Pretty simple... It is fired from a timer event, and is always invoked on the main thread.

This works like a charm...

Now, I sub-class the whole view, and create another view that tries to do the same thing.  It is displayed as a sub-view (full screen) of the main view... Now, UIView.Animate() is a No-op.. It never executes the code inside the block at all.  It is actually the EXACT same function that is being called in the other view...  It is attempting to animate a sub view (a sub-sub-view of the original view...

But it is like the OS is just saying "too bad, so sad, we are not going to work anymore.."  - which is typical of the OS,but that is another topic...

Originally, I tried to just make this view another view that would flip over to from the base view, but apparently, without a navigation controller it won't work, and if you have one then the popup menu that I created will no longer popup...

```
        UIView.Animate (tm, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, () =>
        {
            MapRotating = true;
            _DoRotate ();
        },
        () => {
            MapRotating = false;});
        }
```

The MapRotating = true; never gets called.. I've put this before the animate call, but then it never tries again if the animate fails... This way, it keeps failing forever...

_DoRotate computes the angle to rotate and rotates it (sets a transform)...

Is there a UIView.LastError() method that I can call for it to tell me WHY is it Ignoring my request... (ooh, how about throwing an exception if we passed it something it didn't like?)

-Chris

Comment: OMG I figured it out..... No idea WHY, but here goes...  I changed the code in the timer event to InvokeInMainThread() a method DoTimer(), instead of having that function call InvokeInMainThread() on each of the things it was doing (3) in that method...  Doesn't make any sense, but then... Hey, I'm getting used to it... Anyone can explain?

Comment: Post more code, then someone could probably explain it. Need an example of what `_DoRotate` does.

Comment: All that DoRotate does is compute the angle (that shouldn't make any difference to anything) and then does;
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation ((TotalRotation * 2.0f + 1.0f) * (float)Math.PI / 6);
   
   mvMap.Transform = rotate;

Comment: I did it that way because using a UIView's Transform.Rotate() call does nothing, and has never done anything (that I have figured out).. It seems that one must assign to the Transform property instead of calling the methods on it to change it...